# How to change column width one by one in extjs columns chart?

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

How to change column width of a columns chart one by one? I need charts like this:

```
 _          __
| |  ____  |  |
| | |    | |  |
| | |    | |  |
|_| |____| |__|
```

Comment: Let me see if I understood your question correctly: you want to be able to set the width of your columns individually. But do you want to do this in code, or to give the users the ability to resize columns by themselves?

Comment: Which charting tool you are using?

Comment: @Benoit Garret i want to do this in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
...

series: [
     {
             type: 'column',
             axis: 'left',
             gutter: 10,
             style: {
                   width: 50    //<-- Specify you Column width here
             },
             xField: 'title',                            
             yField: ['totaltodotime', 'workdone'],
             stacked: true,
...
```

- Ext JS documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Column-cfg-style)   for Chart Series column has style as one of the configuration option.
- I added ***width*** attribute followed by required size.

Comment: I want to be able to set the width of my columns individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {                       
                        var color = selectedColor;
                        if (unique condition to identify the column ) {
                            return Ext.apply(attr, {
                                fill: color,
                                width: 100,x:50,y:50

                            });

                        }
                        else(another condition) {
                            return Ext.apply(attr, {
                                fill: color
                                ,width: 50,

                            });
                        }

                    },
you can use record or index or store to identify the column being rendered
```